# Global .gitignore not working, DS_Store files are still showing in untracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

I created my global gitignore:

`vim ~/.gitignore_global`

I add the line:

`.DS_Store`
(I've also tried all different varations like **/.DS_Store)

Then I try to add the global config file:

`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

But it's still not working. I'm certain the files are new and untracked:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    app/code/.DS_Store
```

Why is this not working? I'm baffled.

Comment: That definitely *looks* right. Does your (local) `.git/config` have an overriding, different `core.excludesfile` setting?

Comment: This is what is it my local `.git/config`:

`[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true`

Comment: That looks correct as well. This should all just work, then.